# Can't access website only from laptop

Tags: windows-8.1

I can't access one certain website, and that only on my laptop.
On my phone and even on my virtual machine OS I can visit that site using the same Wifi connection. But not on my laptop.

I have Windows 8.1 and Avast as my AV.
I tried flushing my dns and also a different browser but all that didn't work.

Why is that happening?

Comment: But can you visit other websites? Which website is it that you cannot open?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that one site isn't compatible with the version of Internet Explorer that comes with Windows 8.1. I would recommend trying to browse to that site using Firefox and see if you still get that same issue.

When I upgraded to Windows 8.1 there were a few sites that I couldn't access using Internet Explorer, but once I switched to Firefox those sites worked perfectly.